# What is the equivalent of the following code in tensorflow?

Tags: for-loop, tensorflow

I have the following function:

```
import random

lst = []
for i in range(100):
    lst.append(random.randint(1, 10))

print(lst)

buffer = []

# This is the peace of code which I am interested to convert into tensorflow.
for a in lst:
    buffer.append(a)

    if len(buffer) > 5:
        buffer.pop(0)

    if len(buffer) == 5:
        print(buffer)
```

So, from the code, I need to create a buffer (that could be a variable in tensorflow). This buffer should hold the extracted features from the last `conv layer`. The `variable` will be an input to an `RNN` in my case.

*The advantage of this approach is that when we have large images, and when we need to feed a RNN with a `(batch of images) * (sequence length) * (size of 1 image)`, that will require a very big batch of images to be loaded into the main memory. On the other hand, according to the code above, we will be feeding 1 image at a time using the `Datasets` from tensorflow, or an `input queue` or any other alternative. As a result, we will be storing in memory the feature of size: `batch_size * sequence_length * feature space` .In addition, we can say:*

```
if len(buffer) == n:
    # empty out the buffer after using its elements
    buffer = [] # Or any other alternative way
```

I am aware that I can feed my network `batches` of images, but I  need to accomplish the mentioned code based on some literature.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: can you use tf.FIFOQueue? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/FIFOQueue

Answer (score 2):

I try to regenerate your output using **tf.FIFOQueue** (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/FIFOQueue). I have given my code below with the comments where necessary.

```
BATCH_SIZE = 20

lst = []
for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
    lst.append(random.randint(1, 10))
print(lst)

curr_data = np.reshape(lst, (BATCH_SIZE, 1)) # reshape the tensor so that [BATCH_SIZE 1]

# queue starts here
queue_input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[1]) # Placeholder for feed the data

queue = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=50, dtypes=[tf.int32], shapes=[1]) # Queue define here

enqueue_op = queue.enqueue([queue_input_data])  # enqueue operation
len_op = queue.size()  # chek the queue size

#check the length of the queue and dequeue one if greater than 5
dequeue_one = tf.cond(tf.greater(len_op, 5), lambda: queue.dequeue(), lambda: 0)
#check the length of the queue and dequeue five elemts if equals to 5
dequeue_many = tf.cond(tf.equal(len_op, 5), lambda:queue.dequeue_many(5), lambda: 0)

with tf.Session() as session:
    for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
        _ = session.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict={queue_input_data: curr_data[i]}) # enqueue one element each ietaration
        len = session.run(len_op)  # check the legth of the queue
        print(len)

        element = session.run(dequeue_one)  # dequeue the first element
        print(element)
```

However, following two problems are associated with the above code,

1. Only the **dequeue one** and **dequeue many** operations are available and you cannot see the elements inside the queue (I don't think you will need this since you are looking something like a **pipeline**).
2. I think that **tf.cond** is the only way to implement a **conditional operation** (I couldn't find any other suitable function similar to that). However, since its similar to the **if-then-else statement**, its mandatory to define an operation when the statement is false also (not just having only **if statement** without the **else**). Since **Tensorflow** is all about building a graph I think its necessary to include the two branches (when the condition is true and false).

Moreover, a good explanation for Tensorflow **input pipelines** can be found here (http://ischlag.github.io/2016/11/07/tensorflow-input-pipeline-for-large-datasets/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me know if this is not what you expect exacly .

Comment: @Wijerathne, No, this is not what I am looking for. So do u know how to use (in other words, use the value of the tensor queue.size()) not through sess.run(....) Maybe that would solve the problem.

Comment: Alright, but in my case I am using the Dataset API, so there is no need for tensorflow I guess anymore when we are feeding one image at a time through `feed_dict`. Therefore, I am using `sess.run(iterator.initializer)` after creating a `Session` object. So this is how I am feeding data into my model:
`dataset = dataset_ziped.batch(batch_size) 
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()` Therefore, I need to check the size of the queue not through running `sess.run(len_op)`, but while building the graph model.